# How to use given that equation to find unknown probability?

Tags: probability, statistics, bayes-theorem

I'm working on this question below

> In a survey of working individuals, the probability of being employed in one of the
> three sectors, manufacturing, agriculture and service are given as 0.4, 0.05 and 0.55.
> Researchers are interested in the impact of education. The probability of having a
> degree given that an individual works in manufacturing is 0.7. The probability of
> having a degree given that an individual works in agriculture is 0.05 and the
> probability of having a degree given the individual works in the service sector is 0.60.
>
> a) What is the overall probability that an individual has a degree?

i thought to do

$p(m/h) =\frac{p(M and D)}{P(m)}$

$0.7 =\frac{p(M and D)}{0.4}$
to calculate p(m and d) as 0.28
then i did p (m and d) =P(d)x P(m)
and calculated p(d) as 0.7

m being mechanic and d for a degree

but according to my answer sheet its
a) 0.6125

I can't figure out what I've done wrong any help would be great

Comment: I'd suggest trying to think about it more intuitively before reaching for formulas. Imagine there are a million people. How many of them have each occupation? In each of those groups, how many have a degree? Therefore, how many have a degree in total?

Comment: By the way, your mistake was to assume $P(M\cap D)=P(M)P(D)$. This is only valid if $M$ and $D$ are independent. If being in manufacturing and having a degree were independent, then the probability of having a degree given that you're in manufacturing would just be the probability of having a degree overall (i.e. you would have $P(D|M)=P(D)$), so the given value of 0.7 would be the answer.

Comment: I suggest:  try actual numbers.  Suppose there were $10^4$ people in your sample and they they follow your statistics.  Now count the people with a degree.